# Specific URL for each tab without reloading in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a tab system and I want to be able to go to and url that opens a determined tab. Such as *www.site.com/tab2* (preferentially for SEO) or *www.site.com#tab2*.

I've tried methods like *window.location* or *window.history.pushstate* ([posted here](http://spoiledmilk.dk/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page)) but I didnt know how to make them function.

---

**Javascript:**

```
(function() {

        var $tabsNav    = $('.tabs-nav'),
            $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('li'),
            $tabContent = $('.tab-content');

        $tabContent.hide();
        $tabsNavLis.first().addClass('active').show();
        $tabContent.first().show();

        $tabsNavLis.on('click', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);

            $tabsNavLis.removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $tabContent.hide();

            $( $this.find('a').attr('href') ).fadeIn();

                    var hash = window.location.hash;
                    var tab = parseInt(hash.replace('#',''), 10);
                    $tabsNavLis.eq(tab - 1).click();

            e.preventDefault();
        });

    })();
```

---

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="tabs-nav">

    <li class="active">
        <a href="#1">TAB 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#2">TAB 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#3">TAB 3</a>
    </li>

</ul><!-- end .tabs-nav -->

<div class="tabs-container">
    <div class="tab-content" id="1">

        CONTENT OF TAB 1

    </div><!-- end #tab1 -->

    <div class="tab-content" id="2">

        CONTENT OF TAB 2

    </div><!-- end #tab2 -->

    <div class="tab-content" id="3">

        CONTENT OF TAB 3

    </div><!-- end #tab3 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a lil script up to look at the page's hash via `window.location.hash`.

So, on document ready, get the hash, then simulate a click to the proper tab. Something like this...

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var tab = parseInt(hash.replace('#',''), 10);
$tabsNavLis.eq(tab - 1).click();
```

Tho, this only works like it does because your hashes have the index of the tab in it. But you see what can be done once you have the hash. I hope this helps!

EDIT:

This is how it should be...tho i have not tried the code myself. Put it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you want me to mess with it some more.

```
(function($){
    $(function() {

        var $tabsNav = $('.tabs-nav'),
            $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('li'),
            $tabContent = $('.tab-content');

        $tabContent.hide();
        $tabsNavLis.first().addClass('active').show();
        $tabContent.first().show();

        $tabsNavLis.on('click', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);

            $tabsNavLis.removeClass('active');
            $this.addClass('active');
            $tabContent.hide();

        });

        var hash = window.location.hash;
        var tab = parseInt(hash.replace('#', ''), 10);
        $tabsNavLis.eq(tab - 1).click();

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I just add that after `var $tabsNav    = $('.tabs-nav'),
            $tabsNavLis = $tabsNav.children('li'),
            $tabContent = $('.tab-content');` ?

Comment: Add it after your click handler. And be sure this code is all running inside a document ready (`$(function(){ // your code here });`), or at the bottom of your html (right before the closing body tag).

Comment: Yes its running inside a document ready so it would be like is now edited on my post? Do I have to delete the `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: This seems to delete the content of the tab

Comment: Well that has nothing to do with my code. You need to get this into a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/ otherwise its really hard to help.

Comment: I would also recommend using a tab system that already has these smaller issues worked out, like [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).